# Prevent multiple axios calls in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have the following 2 methods where `publishBuild` gets called on a button click:

```
publishBuild () {
     var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state)
     stateCopy.errors = []
     this.postBuild(stateCopy);
 }

async postBuild(stateCopy) {
    try {
        await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/build',
            data: {
                title: stateCopy.title,
                description: DOMPurify.sanitize(this.converter.makeHtml(stateCopy.value)),
                type: stateCopy.type === 'public' ? 0 : 1,
                mode: stateCopy.mode,
                tags: "testtag",
                profession: stateCopy.selectedClass.id,
                encryption: stateCopy.encryption
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            window.location.href = response.data.redirect_link
        })
        .catch(errors => {
            if (errors.response.data.title !== undefined) {
                stateCopy.errors.push(errors.response.data.title[0])
            }
            if (errors.response.data.description !== undefined) {
                stateCopy.errors.push(errors.response.data.description[0])
            }
            if (errors.response.data.type !== undefined) {
                stateCopy.errors.push(errors.response.data.type[0])
            }
            if (errors.response.data.mode !== undefined) {
                stateCopy.errors.push(errors.response.data.mode[0])
            }
            if (errors.response.data.tags !== undefined) {
                stateCopy.errors.push(errors.response.data.tags[0])
            }
            if (errors.response.data.profession !== undefined) {
                stateCopy.errors.push(errors.response.data.profession[0])
            }
            if (errors.response.data.encryption !== undefined) {
                stateCopy.errors.push(errors.response.data.encryption[0])
            }
        });
        this.setState(stateCopy)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

The code works just fine and the data is passed to the URL. The problem is however if the user clicks more than once on the button, it will trigger multiple calls. So if in my case a user clicks on the button 5 times he will actually create 5 different pages with the same content. What would be the best way to prevent this?

Comment: Disable the button once user hit it. Now, if request is successful, you'll redirect the user. Otherwise, enable the button again in `catch` part, along with errors.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at debouncing. It's exactly what you want.

With debouncing you'll set a delay. The debounce will allow the first click to go through instantly, but will ignore any additional clicks until the delay period has past. Additional clicks within the delay period will reset the delay.

The advantage to this is the button remains usable (so it's not disabled, in case you need to use it later), but it'll prevent the button from being clickable multiple times in quick succession.

A popular way to get access to a debounce function is to use `underscore.js`. If you chose underscore your code would look like this:

```
const sendRequest = _.debounce(() => {
 // Code to send request
}, delayInMs);
```

Or in your case:

```
const sendRequest = _.debounce(publishBuild, delayInMs);
```

Then on your button you would call the sendRequest function onClick like:

```
<button onClick={sendRequest}>Send request</button>
```